# Copy/Paste only cells with values

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to do the following?

```
Source          Target         Result
|1| |F|         |0|0|0|        |1|0|F|        
| | | |   ->    |0| |0|   =    |0| |0|        
|1| |F|         |0|0|0|        |1|0|F|
```

i.e copy from a source table with empty cells and paste only the cells with values, not overwriting if the source has empty cells at those places

Comment: What have you research or attempted so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PasteSpecial with the *Skip blanks* option.  Say we have:

[image]

and we copy from **A1:C3** to **F1:H3** using this option.  We will have:

[image]